# Why isn' t typescript recognizing the union type in this statement?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type testUnion = Array<any> | string;

class testClass {
testProp: testUnion;
}

const bar = new testClass()
bar.testProp.forEach(...) //property forEach does not exist on type testUnion
```

However testUnion is an array OR a string and the property for each exists on the Array class. Why is typescript not seeing it as an Array or a String. The only intelisense I get is a method 'valueOf'

any ideas?

**EDIT**
full code below, the loadTrait method in the Developer class is what is in question, I also included the Trait class and all the relevant interfaces just incase there are any other suggestions.

```
interface devInit {
    locations: Array<Location>;
    traits: Array<Trait>;
    props: developerProp;
    name: string;
}

interface developerProp {
    acceptedMaritalStatuses: maritalStatusType;
    ageTop: number;
    ageBottom: number;
    income: number;
    majorCCRequired: boolean;
}
class Developer {
    locations: traitLocationType;
    props: developerProp;
    name: string;
    private traits: Array<Trait> = [];
    constructor(init: devInit) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
        $notesApi.subscribe((_notes) => {
            this.notesApi = _notes;
        });
    }
    private notesApi: notesApiType;
    //only load after traits have been loaded.
    private loadExternalNotes() {
        //@ts-ignore
        if (_notes === '') return;
        this.locations.forEach((_location) => {
            const gifts = new Note(
                'gifts',
                this.notesApi[this.name][_location.name].gifts
            );
            const notes = new Note(
                'gifts',
                this.notesApi[this.name][_location.name].notes
            );
            _location.addNote(gifts);
            _location.addNote(notes);
        });
    }
    private loadTraits() {
        this.traits.forEach((_trait) => {
            _trait.runRules();
            if (!_trait.key) return;
            if (_trait.key === 'locations') {
                if(Array.isArray(_trait.value))
                _trait.value.forEach((_traitValue) => {
                    this.locations.push(_traitValue);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

class Trait {
    constructor(traitKey: traitKeyType, traitValue: traitValueType) {
        this._key = traitKey;
        this._value = traitValue;
    }
    private _key: traitKeyType;
    private _value: Array<any> | string;
    private status = false;
    private notes: Array<Note> = [];
    private rules: Array<Rule> = [];
    get key() {
        if (!this.status) return null;
        return this._key;
    }
    get value() {
        if (!this.status) return null;
        return this._value;
    }
    addRule(rule: Rule) {
        this.rules.push(rule);
        return this;
    }
    runRules() {
        const getInfoFromRules = (_rule: Rule) => {
            _rule.run();
            this.notes.push(_rule.note);
            return _rule.status;
        };
        this.status = this.rules.map(getInfoFromRules).indexOf(false) === -1;
    }
}
type traitValueType = Array<any> | string;
// | maritalStatusType
// | traitLocationType
// | traitLocationType
// | boolean;

type maritalStatusType = 'married' | 'coHab' | 'singleMale' | 'singleFemale'[];
type traitLocationType = Array<Location>;
```

Comment: Always read the last line in error message "Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'." :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I now see the hidden clue at the end! lol

Comment: There are iterable behaviors common to both types that will work like `[...testProp]` and `for..of`

Comment: so, is this correct, that if the Trait _key is locations, then the Trait _value must be an array, otherwise, the Trait _value must be a string? but you're not actually enforcing that in your typings, it's just enforced by convention in your code? if so, I'd say that's dangerous code, because you in the future (or some other dev) could forget a convention and misuse the key location, and then you have either a runtime error if using an assertion, or a logical error if using a type check

Comment: You are correct if Trait._key is locations then Trait._value is an array however I don't understand what you mean by enforcing it in typings just by convention in code.

Comment: i mean that your Trait type definition doesn't enforce that the key locations must have an array value, so someone could create a Trait with key locations and a string value, but you they shouldn't due to conventions. You could write a type definition though I believe where ts would throw an error if someone tried to do so.

Comment: how would I do if 'location' then Array<location>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because it can be an array OR a string.  TS doesn't know which it is, you have to tell it...

you can use a type check:

```
if (Array.isArray(bar.testProp)) {
  bar.testProp.forEach(...)  // this is fine 
}
```

or if you KNOW it's in fact an array, you can use a type assertion:

```
(bar.testProp as Array<any>).forEach(...) // also fine
```

Comment: with a typecheck like I have in my answer. it can't know if it's a string or an array without a type check or a type assertion.

Comment: the assertion is the way to go, I already have a check to see the value of the key, it would be redundant to have another if statement to check if it is an array because I know if the key is of a specific value it is an array

Comment: my 2 cents, a lot of type assertions are usually a sign of something wrong in your code or that you could be doing better. If you're already checking the value of the key, it seems like you could restructure so that you don't need to run that check redundantly and just run based off the initial check... this isn't always the case but it is a useful rule of thumb

Comment: Hmmm... I'm pretty new and self taught, I'll post the actual code in the question would you mind taking a look?

Comment: yea I'll take a look if you post it